# Getting Cannot read property 'question' of undefined when trying to display an initial joke

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am currently learning to create a React app on my own, and I decided to build a joke app from scratch with no tutorial, and so far I have been able to achieve the following:

1. Pull a random joke from a local json file I created and display it in the browser
2. Then create an onClick event that would display a joke when triggered.
3. Create a homepage where a user can select the category of jokes they wish to see.

**Issue**

Now the issue I am having is the following: 
When the user selects a joke category from the homepage, in this case Sports Jokes, the page (Sports Jokes) displays no joke until he/she clicks on the "click here for a joke" button.  I would like for a joke to be displaying already when the user selects this category. 
How can I achieve that?

**My initial approach gave me the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined**

In my initial approach I created a separate function called getInitialJoke, which returns a random joke. Then in the render, I created a variable called const `{initialJoke`} which is  `this.getInitialJoke();` and then the joke would be displayed as

```
<div>
   <p>{initialJoke.question}</p>
   <p>{initialJoke.answer}</p>
</div>
```

I would leave `getRandomJoke` alone since that was created for my onClick event in order to display a new joke with each click.

```
import React from 'react'
import SportsJokesData from '../data/SportsJokesData';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Buttons.css';
const initialState = {
  randomJoke: []
};

class SportsJokesApi extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getRandomJoke = this.getRandomJoke.bind(this);
    this.state = initialState;
  }

  getInitialJoke() {
    return SportsJokesData[(SportsJokesData.length* Math.random()) << 0]
  }
  getRandomJoke() {
    this.setState({
      randomJoke: SportsJokesData[(SportsJokesData.length * Math.random()) << 0]
    });
  }


  render() {
    const {randomJoke} = this.state;
    const {initialJoke} = this.getInitialJoke();

    return (
      <React.Fragment >
        <div>

        <p>{initialJoke.question}</p>
        <p>{initialJoke.answer}</p>
        </div>

        <div className="flex">
          <p>{randomJoke.question}</p> 
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <p>{randomJoke.answer}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <button class="btn joke" onClick = {this.getRandomJoke}>Click here for joke </button> 
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <Link to="/ProgrammingJokes">
            <button className="btn programming">Programming Jokes</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <Link to="/DadJokes">
            <button className="btn dad">Dad Jokes</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <Link to="/SpanishJokes">
            <button className="btn spanish">Chistes en ñ</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <Link to="/">
            <button className="btn home">Home Page</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment >
    );
  }
}
export default SportsJokesApi;
```

This is how I have my local json folder set up:

```
const SportsJokesData = [
    {
        id: "1",
        question: "What did the baseball glove say to the ball?",
        answer: "Catch ya later!"

    }
]
export default SportsJokes
```

Comment: is that typo in the export default statement in your code?

Comment: Just fixed it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

State update is asynchronous, so it might be empty before it's filled with your data. Try doing some safety checking, like `randomJoke?.answer`. Plus you have `randomJoke` intialized as an array, you should use `{}` instead.

#### Edit 1

use correct term in export.

```
const SportsJokesData = [
    {
        id: "1",
        question: "What did the baseball glove say to the ball?",
        answer: "Catch ya later!"

    }
]
export default SportsJokesData;
```

#### Edit 2

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-jang-7510v?file=/src/App.js) is a working version.